# splitting on each comma, but not if there is a space after

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to preg_split this string but keep `Barcelona, Spain` in the same case.
This is my code but it doesnt work:

```
<?php
$v = 'test,lolo,Barcelona, Spain,test4';
$test = preg_split('/(,)^\s/', $v);
print_r($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead. `/,(?!\s)/` http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

Comment: Awesome ! Work fine !